# How to crypt and decrypt a file using oauth or openid in python?

Tags: python, authentication, encryption, oauth

A user wants to encrypt a file. He does not want to generate keys or passwords. User has a google-account (or similar). Is it possible to write a program that uses third party authentication (or similar) to encrypt and decrypt the file? How?

The program should work as follows:

- user says 'save'
- third party authentication window pops up
- user authenticates with the third party service
- third party service returns some token/key?
- file is encrypted with the token
- **time passes**
- user says 'open'
- third party authentication window pops up
- user authenticates with the third party service
- third party service returns **the same** token/key?
- file is decrypted with the token

Is the above possible? Is the behavior possible with other methods than oauth or openid? Is there a possibility to add a password for random users or multiple accounts?

Comment: Third party authentication is just authenticating the user, it is different than encrypting/decrypting some data. Authentication is a different thing and encrypting/decrypting a data is a different thing. For encrypting/decryption you have to use some encryption/decryption algorithms. So, I think it is not possible to use merely third party authentication to encrypt/decrypt the data. You can use third party authentication to authenticate the user to encrypt/decrypt a data using some encryption/decryption algorithms.

Comment: @pss ok, how do I allow the user to decrypt the file only if he is authenticated? The decryption program is located in the users hard drive.

Comment: Well in that case you have create an application that first authenticates the user and if the users provides correct credentials then he/she may use the decryption algorithm to decrypt the data. If the user doesn't provides correct credentials then the application won't allow the user to do any thing. This is just like some folder locker software https://www.google.com/#q=folder+lock+software You can do the encryption/decryption stuff on the client/users's machine and then maybe you can upload the data in cloud. For eg: https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/boxcryptor